# How to retain single session for the test in Specflow with specflow+excel

Tags: c#, session, selenium, bdd, specflow

When login to google system, I should be able to naviagate to all menus

```
@Login
Scenario: Successful Login to Google
 Given Google system launched
 When Login with XYZ
 Then Google main page displayed
@menuNavigate
Scenario Outline: Navigate to page from google menu 
    Given User navigates to <Tab> using the tabs
    When The Page is completely loaded with <Header>
    Then the result should be that a control with controlId <ControlId> is displayed on the screen

@source:menuNavigate.xlsx
Scenarios:
| Tab | Header  | ControlId |
```

@Login test is successful. When @menuNavigate test is executed, it launches separate session.

Is there any way to continue the rest of the test with same browser session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this on a per feature basis (ie you can reuse the same browser in all of the scenarios in a feature) by creating your browser instance in the [`[BeforeFeature]` hook](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks) and then using this in each scenario. As long as your `[beforeFeature` and `[BeforeScenario]` hooks are in the same class then you can declare a static field which holds your browser instance and populate this in the `[BeforeFeature]` hook and reuse the field in the `[BeforeScenario]` hook.

However consider whether you really want to do this. What will happen if your scenarios are run in a different order? Nothing guarantees test execution order. Or in parallel?

I highly doubt that this approach will scale well in the long term.

If you want to have some setup in common then [create a background](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow) or create a step to do the setup and call this from each scenario. You can even [call other steps from this setup step](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions) if you want the setup step to perform some actions which are already used in another test.